# Vertex in Feynman diagram

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry, feynman-diagrams, interactions

The Taylor expansion for $e^x$ to 2nd order is
$$e^x = 1 + x + x^2/2$$
If we look at the unitary operator for the $\phi^4$ theory
$$\exp\left[-i\frac{\lambda}{4!}\int{\phi^4}dt\right] , $$
we can also expand it in this way. Yet when writing the Feynman rules for a theory, we say that each vertex gives a factor of $$-i\lambda.$$ This makes sense, but what about the factors $\frac{1}{2!}, \frac{1}{3!}, …$ in the Taylor series? Why aren’t these included in the Feynman rules. In other words, shouldn’t it be that for the $n$ vertices, we get a factor of $$\frac{(-i\lambda)^n}{n!}~?$$

Comment: Hint: Is there only one way of contracting the fields from the expansion via Wick's theorem?

Comment: I know there are 4! ways at the vertex, but this only takes care of the 4! In the interaction term. It doesn’t take care of the 1/2!, 1/3! etc, at least it seems

Comment: How about a labelling redundancy of the vertices?

Comment: If you work through a careful derivation of the Feynman rules, you will see those factors are all accounted for, and typically we choose to normalize couplings in the Lagrangian so these factors cancel. The tricky part is getting these prefactors right when exchanging two (or more) lines or vertices in a Feynman diagram gives you an identical diagram. To account for this situation you need to worry about [symmetry factors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman_diagram#Symmetry_factors).

Answer (score 2):

Briely speaking, the combinatorial factors and factorials are included via the very last Feynman rule, which says that one should divide with the [symmetry factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman_diagram#Symmetry_factors) $S$ of the Feynman diagram.